# Problem returning context_processor data to html for looping

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, return

I'm trying to add categories field to navigation. So far I've made context_processor which querys all the car brands. In my navigation I'm loopin all of the brands and this works. I also want to add dropdowns which contains certain car models for certain car brands. I think the problem lays in returning right data, that is loopable in my `_base.html`.

_base.html

```
<div class="flex pt-3 container w-full">

  {% for item in car_brands %}

    <button id="dropdown-button" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown-{{item.id}}" class="py-2.5 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 uppercase" type="button">{{item}}</button>
    <div id="dropdown-{{item.id}}" class="hidden shadow w-44 bg-gray-100">
      <ul aria-labelledby="dropdown-button">
        {% for model in models %}
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="inline-flex w-full px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-50">{{ model }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>

  {% endfor %}
```

context_processors.py

```
from .models import CarBrandCategory, CarModel

def brand_catalogue(request):
    car_brands = CarBrandCategory.objects.all()


    for brand in car_brands:
        models = [model for model in CarModel.objects.filter(brand_id=brand.id)]
        print(models)


    return {
        'car_brands': car_brands,
        'models': models
        }
```

If printing, it will give me different lists, consists of different models, eg.

```
[<CarModel: X4>, <CarModel: X5>, <CarModel: 3. Seeria>]
[<CarModel: A4>, <CarModel: A6>, <CarModel: A8>]
[<CarModel: C klass>, <CarModel: S-Klass>]
```

Models:

Product Category model:

```
from django.db import models

# Main product category

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category_description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
    
# Condition category

class ProductCondition(models.Model):
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.condition
    
# Band Category

class CarBrandCategory(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name
    
# Brand Model Category
    
class CarModel(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(CarBrandCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='model')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model
```

Product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    product_description_short = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    product_condition = models.ForeignKey(ProductCondition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    product_manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    product_location_state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_location_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    product_delivery_time = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    product_brand = models.ForeignKey(CarBrandCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='brand')
    product_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_img_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=new_image_path, blank=True)
    product_img_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=new_image_path, blank=True)
    product_img_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=new_image_path, blank=True)
    product_img_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to=new_image_path, blank=True)
    product_img_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to=new_image_path, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    product_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_title
```

I was wondering if anyone has experience with this kind of solutions and what could be the most optimal way to create this kind of solution?

I've created a list of different car models, but I'm unable to return it to HTML. I want each car brand in my navigation menu to have dropdown, which consists of certain car models.

Comment: Please share your models

Comment: In this particular context, you don't have to query models separately. You can use the reverse related name for querying all the related models of a category.

    `{% for model in item.model %}<li><a href="#" class="inline-flex w-full px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-50">{{ model }}</a></li>{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things, you can work with:

```
from .models import CarBrandCategory


def brand_catalogue(request):
    return {'car_brands': CarBrandCategory.objects.prefetch_related('model')}
```

Then in the template, you use:

```
<ul>
    {% for brand in car_brands %}
        <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}
        {% for model in brand.model.all %}
            <li>{{ model.model }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```